# How to keep 'active' class to li tag when redirect to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, adminlte

I have 2 menus manage category and manage product, it turns 'active' when clicks. Problem is, there is button 'add product' under manage product menu, When I go to add product page menu 'manage product' don't keep 'active'.

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <section class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="manage_category.php">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Manage category</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                <li>
                <a href="manage_products.php">
                <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Manage products</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    // for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
    $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the html code of your `Add Products`

Comment: is that "add product" page is different? or it is in "manage products" page only? if it is different then url doesnt match and class will not get added.

Comment: you'd have to have a rule which tells the system which pages are considered part of the "manage product" menu. At the moment it does a simple match on the current URL. If the URL doesn't match the href of the menu item, it won't be highlighted as active. Either identify a pattern by which it can match them (e.g. presence of the phrase "product" in the filename would work in your extremely simple example) or you'll have to have some sort of list of pages somewhere, mapping them to which menu item should be highlighted when that page is visited, and some code to read the list and act accordingly

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan : problem is in jquery code above, 'add product' is different page that contains only form where user add product details and redirect to 'manage product' page. so i need to keep active 'manage product' menu when user works on 'add product' page

Comment: @bharatparmar check my answer

Comment: @bharatparmar - Meloman's answer will work.. It is correct. If you use a debugger (e.g. Chrome debugger) and put a break-point on the line I suggest you will see the problem. You have to understand what the problem is rather than clutching at straws

Answer (score 1):

you can add hidden link for 'add product' in your menu

```
<li>
 <a href="manage_products.php">
  <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Manage products</span>
 </a>
 <a href="add_product.php" style="display:none"></a>
</li>
```

and your javascript code should works as it's

Answer (score 1):

Your window.location returns entire url not only the page.

This is working :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
    jQuery('ul.sidebar-menu a').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('href') == url)
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: on page 'mange product' there is product listing and on listing i have 'add product' button. when click it user redirect to 'add product' page that is different page contains only form where user add product details and redirect to 'manage product' page. so i need to keep active 'manage product' menu when user works on 'add product' page

Comment: I understand what you want to do. please try again, I made some modifications in the code.

Comment: thank for trying , but need to tell you that there is no menu names 'add_product.php' in my ul li tag (`<ul class="sidebar-menu">`). i have main menu name 'manage_product.php' on this page i have button add product and so on adding product page i want keep my main menu name 'active'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that url (window.location) != this.href in your filter.

this.href will be e.g. manage_products.php but window.location is an object. (Check the MDN docs for window.location). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Even window.location.href will still give you the full url. But -
 window.location.pathname might be close to what you want.

If you debug your code on this line: return this.href == url; and examine the values you will see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if "add product" is not different page then Try below code.

```
var parameter = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
parameter.add_endRequest(function () {
var url = window.location;

    // for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
    $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');

})
```

Comment: no, 'add product' is a diffrent form page that add product details and redirect to 'manage product' page.

Comment: i dint understand will the url be same as when u clicked on "manage products"?

Comment: no , url will different like www.abc.com/manage_products.php and on this page has a button 'add product', when it clicks redirect to www.abc.com/add_products.php, so i want menu 'manage product' as active when even user add products on 'add product'